# Apache Camel: Set body from resource

Tags: spring, classpath, apache-camel

Basically, I'm trying to do this (incorrect code!):

```
  <camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>resource:classpath:/myfiles/file.xml</camel:simple>
  </camel:setBody>
```

How would you do this properly?

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can possible try with

```
<to uri="language:constant:resource:classpath:/myfiles/file.xml"/>
```

To use the language component: http://camel.apache.org/language.html
To load the content.

Comment: Hi Claus, in fact both are possible. I had just forgotten to upgrade to Camel 2.11 ... By the way, shouldn't it be "language://" in your URI?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In DSL style like this:

```
.setBody(constant("resource:classpath:foo/bar/baz/some.sql"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In camel xml dsl you can do this way.

```
<setBody>
    <!--fileName with location to be uploaded -->
    <constant>/data/myfiles/file.xml</constant>
</setBody>
<convertBodyTo type="java.io.File"/>
```